# Can I Send a custom class from asp .net 4.0 website to a WCF .net 4.0 service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, .net-4.0

I want to create a wrapper class called Report that contains dictionaries and lists and such in my website generated by 100-1000 fields from the website page, then send it to my WCF service.

I have tested my connected I can send a string or int and it works fine, I have not tried to send a custom class (im assuming the class would be attached BOTH to the website (ASP.NET 4.0) and the WCF service (.NET 4.0) in order to make this work.

The idea is to create the report class, fill it up with my data then send it to the wcf (the interface would have a [OperationContract] and then it would take a parameter of type Report, and then I could do something with that object on the WCF service side to pull data from dictionaries and lists from the object and send it to a database.

So I know right know my website and wcf are talking together as I have sent a string and returned an int it worked fine.

But I am wondering if I can pass over a class that I created (assuming both the website and wcf both have the same class file)?

Comment: Yes. But I wonder why you need confirmation from random people on the internet. Go and try.

Comment: @nvoigt I was looking to confirm because It would take me a couple days to set it up this way, if it wasnt going to work then it would have been wasted days for a nearing deadline.

Comment: @Kairan...I am trying to do the same thing -- Did you ever get the report params class over to the web-service?  Did your service generate the report using RDLC / SSRS? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you need a confirmation by a totally trustworthy stranger on the internet, **yes** it works that way.

If you decide that listening to random people isn't going to help with the deadline, you may want to open a new WCF project in Visual Studio. It will generate a default service called `Service1` that already does exactly what you want. It uses a user defined type in it's interface. Open a new ASP project and reference that service. The class will even be generated for you by the Visual Studio Wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Hats off to the smart guys on SOF.com, but @Kairan - the class you made it in either Business Layer  - this should have a parallel SOA layered Datacontract(aka class) and those fields which should have publicly available and entire class should be serializable ( which should not have fields which are not serializable- like sqlconnection.. . I know crude way of checking whether all classes are serializable or not of a ASp.net web application - Just set  in web.config - and by navigating all pages, one can understand all the objects are serializable :)